# Apache Camel + Spring-WS Issue How to make sure acknowledgement reaches before response

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache-camel, spring-ws

1.Below Asynchoronus spring-ws application called from Camel.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <camel:route id="inputRequest">
                <camel:from uri="spring-ws:rootqname:{http://www.example.com/fgh}Application?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping" />
            <camel:to uri="bean:ApplicationEndpoint"/>
    </camel:route> 
    <camel:route id ="jmsListener">
            <camel:from uri="weblogic:queue:jms/InboundQueue?mapJmsMessage=false"/>
            <camel:bean ref="ApplicationMDP" method="onMessage"/>
    </camel:route> 
</camelContext>
```

2. ApplicationEndpoint : It contains the validation information and once done it will put information in the Queue.
3. After completion of step 2 it will return to client with 202 Acknowledgement automatically without any http post.
4. jmsListener/ApplicationMDP: It will look for any inbound message in queue and start processing the request and finally after completing happy path we do http post to send response to client.

Issue I am facing here is :
Sometime I heard from client they are receiving the Response before Acknowledgement which causing big issue. I need some advice how we can make sure Acknowledgment reaches 
Before http post response. Appreciate your help in advance.